# positive real numbers satisfying an equation

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a,b,c$ are positive real numbers that satisfy $\dfrac {\frac {a^4} {bc} + \frac {b^4} {ac} + \frac {c^4} {ab}} 8 = \dfrac {a^5 + b^5 + c^5} {2c^4 + b^4 + 2a^3 + 4a}$, find the value of $a^2$.

Answer (score 2):

On simplification,

$$2c^4+b^4+2a^3+4a=8abc$$

But by AM GM inequality,

$$\dfrac{2c^4+b^4+2a^3+4a}4\ge\sqrt[4]{2c^4\cdot b^4\cdot2a^3\cdot4a}$$

Do you when does the equality occur?

Comment: when all elements are same.thanks.

Comment: As always, AM GM makes (almost) magic.I address the problem by a longer road, the cubic equation (not without some interest).